# Any ideas on how to batch delete iPhone albums from photo library?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, ssh, jailbreak

**Problem:** I have a friend's iPhone that I am working with who had some 3rd party Canon app that created an overwhelming amount of "Albums" (5848499495 of them to be exact!!).

[Refer to this video](https://youtu.be/1odQHYewMzU)

Obviously, this definitely shouldn't happen and we're trying to see what's the best way to delete all of them.

I was thinking of accessing the files via SSH on the iPhone to see if these "Albums" are represented as directories somewhere in the iPhone's file structure and run some type of shell script to batch remove files as we would on our Macs but I realize that this will require some jailbreaking which we're trying to avoid doing if possible. But will consider it if it's easier to do it that way.

I also tried to see if there were Command Line tools for the iPhone to directly access the root folder to see if we could find the directory but I realize that there are permission issues associated with accessing the iPhone's files without jailbreaking.

These albums are stored locally on the phone, and it's not in iCloud. We tried to see if these folders show up on Mac's photo app after syncing but because they are empty folders, it doesn't show on the app.

Note: we're on a Mac, and the model is an iPhone X running the latest iOS 14.

I'm all out of ideas and any help would be wonderful.

Thanks!

Comment: You can access its filesystem using Windows without Jailbreaking. There used to be a very neat GUI utility few years ago. Where you could access it. I'm not sure it still works as after IOS 6 or 7 they increased the security. BTW if you jailbreak the iphone it doesn't harm except voids the warranty.

Comment: if it's going to take a long time to delete the folders - have you considered restoring from a backup and excluding the photos, hen restoring them from iCloud?